# How to add HTML5 history.pushState() to ajax callback?

Tags: ajax

Somethink like this not working:

```
$commands[] = ajax_command_invoke(null, 'history.pushState', array(NULL, NULL, 'path'));
```

Comment: Find answer, but not sure is it drupal way: in ajax_callback_function:   `$commands[] = ajax_command_invoke(null, 'custom_command_history', array('path'));` and in custom js file: `(function($) {
  $.fn.custom_command_history = function(data) {
    history.pushState(null, null, data);
  };
})(jQuery);`